# selectionStart not updating on focus of input field

Tags: javascript, html, events, onfocus

In my application, I have an input field. I am using the `selectionStart` property of the input element. Everything is working fine when we get the `selectionStart` value on the## Heading ## `keyup` event. But when I use the `selectionStart` on the focus of the input element it is not updating ie. getting value `0`. I could not find the reason.

**JS:**

```
onKeyup(event) {
    let selectionIndex = event.target.selectionStart;
    console.log(selectionIndex);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <input [(ngModel)]="enteredText" (focus)="onKeyup($event)" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)"/>
</section>
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you give an `id` to your input element and then on keyup look for it using `document.getElementById('elementId')` after which you get the `selectionStart` property

Comment: Not sure, but try without arg `onKeyup() {
    let selectionIndex = event.target.selectionStart;
    console.log(selectionIndex);
}` in js

Comment: It works fine. Check thisout - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrphcs

Comment: @AdityaBhave, In the stackblitz the error getting reproduced. On focus, the start and end indexes are 0,0 only. Please check.

Comment: @AllanMogusu, I used that too. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: @SaiUnique Try adding eventlistener on `(mouseup)` as well. I updated the stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrphcs

Comment: @AdityaBhave if you observe, the value is updating lately. By the time, my code execution is happening.

Comment: @SaiUnique I removed `(focus)` event handler and that delay is gone. Please check the stackblitz again. Is there any more code you are executing in the event handler ?